# Issue using Swift’s URLSession Library on Ubuntu to fetch data from an API

Tags: swift, ubuntu, runtime-error, virtual-machine

When attempting to call an API from Swift using the following code I get an unknown error at runtime as shown below. Using Wireshark I was able to confirm that the request is being properly sent to API and that the API is responding correctly with the expected data, however I have been unable to receive that data properly from within Swift.

```swift
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

/// Defines the possible errors
public enum URLSessionAsyncErrors: Error {
    case invalidUrlResponse, missingResponseData
}

public extension URLSession {
     func asyncData(from url: URL) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse) {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            let task = self.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let error = error {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    return
                }
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: URLSessionAsyncErrors.invalidUrlResponse)
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: URLSessionAsyncErrors.missingResponseData)
                    return
                }
                continuation.resume(returning: (data, response))
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}

let urlLink = URL(string: "https://trial.serviceobjects.com/AV3/api.svc/GetBestMatchesJson?BusinessName=&Address=27%20E%20Cota%20St&Address2=Suite%20500&City=Santa%20Barbara&State=CA&PostalCode=93101&LicenseKey=ws72-soa1-dev1")
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.asyncData(from: urlLink!)

print(response)
print(data)
```

The result of running the code is the following error message:

```
Swift/ErrorType.swift:200: Fatal error: Error raised at top level: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)" 
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1f4966eb80 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalErrorInFile + 112
1    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1f4936043f <unavailable> + 1442879
2    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1f49360257 <unavailable> + 1442391
3    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1f4935f060 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 364
4    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1f493bdec6 <unavailable> + 1826502
5    swift                              0x000055c44836ce2b <unavailable> + 20011
6    libswift_Concurrency.so            0x00007f1f498b10ce <unavailable> + 274638
7    libswift_Concurrency.so            0x00007f1f498b1840 swift_job_run + 92
8    libdispatch.so                     0x00007f1f499cdf45 <unavailable> + 192325
9    libdispatch.so                     0x00007f1f499cebbd <unavailable> + 195517
10   libdispatch.so                     0x00007f1f499d6002 <unavailable> + 225282
11   libc.so.6                          0x00007f1f48e94b43 <unavailable> + 609091
12   libc.so.6                          0x00007f1f48f26a00 <unavailable> + 1206784
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I have tried the standard `dataTask` function multiple times and still receive the same -1 error code so I am certain the issue is not the modifications for the `URLSession` I included above.

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorunknown) the -1 error is an unknown error which has made this extremely difficult to debug.

To give greater context, I am using Swift version 5.8.1 on an Ubuntu version 22.04.3 virtual machine hosted on virtual box version 7.0.10 on a windows 11 pc.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or know to fix it?

Comment: Apple/Swift requires `https`, did you setup your NSAppTransportSecurity to allow `http` ? Or simply use `https://....`

Comment: That was leftover from debugging. It doesn't work with https either

Answer (score 0):

try this approach, using `https` and a `Task` to wrap your api call, works for me:

```
 Task {
     let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.asyncData(from: urlLink!)
     print("\n----> response: \(response) ")
     print("\n----> data: \(data) ")
     print("------> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)\n")
 }
```